# Showing that the Riemann invariant $\frac{1}{2} (u^2+v^2) + \int \frac{c(p)^2}{p} dp $ is conserved along the characteristic $dy/dx = v/u$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, hyperbolic-equations

I need to show that the Riemann invariant $R = \frac{1}{2} (u^2+v^2) + \int \frac{c(p)^2}{p} dp $ is conserved along the characteristic $dy/dx = v/u$. My system of equations are:
\begin{aligned}
(pu)_x + (pv)_y &= 0 \\
p(uu_x + vu_y) + c(p)^2p_x &= 0 \\
p(uv_x +vv_y)+c(p)^2p_y &= 0
\end{aligned}

The system is hyperbolic if $u^2 + v^2 > c^2$ where $c=c(p)$ (cf. [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3015087/418542)). The left eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda = dy/dx = v/u$ is $(0,1,v/u)$. To find the Riemann invariant I do:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & v/u
\end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix} 
u & p & 0 \\ 
c^2 & pu & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & pu 
\end{pmatrix}
\frac{d}{dx}\begin{pmatrix} p \\ u \\ v\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix} 
$$
which gives me
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
c^2 & pu & pv
\end{pmatrix}
\frac{d}{dx}\begin{pmatrix} p \\ u \\ v\end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix} 
$$
I am stuck on the final part as to how this implies that $\frac{d}{dx}[R] =0$. I am struggling to see how $\frac{d}{dx} \int \frac{c^2(p)}{p}dp = \frac{c^2(p) {dp}/{dx}}{p}$ which would make $\frac{d}{dx}[R] =0$.